# Is there a way to automatically strip leading space from Apache commons-cli option value?

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

Consider the following example:

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Option;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;

public class ApacheCommonsCliWhitespaceTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Options options = new Options();
    Option option = new Option("t", "test", true, "test description");
    options.addOption(option);

    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();

    String[] parameters = new String[1];

    parameters[0] = "-t ping";
    CommandLine result = parser.parse(options, parameters);
    System.out.println("*" + result.getOptionValue("t") + "*");

    parameters[0] = "-test ping";
    result = parser.parse(options, parameters);
    System.out.println("*" + result.getOptionValue("t") + "*");
  }
}
```

The result will be

```
* ping*
* ping*
```

Is there really no way to remove the leading space automatically? I would have expected that to be a common use case.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
result.getOptionValue("t").trim()
```

Comment: That is a given, but I was specifically asking about that happening automatically.

Comment: AFAIK, this is the only way

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it feasible to adjust this in your case, but it seems Commons CLI wants the format `-arg=value`, so the following results in `*ping*`:

```
    parameters[0] = "-test=ping";
    result = parser.parse(options, parameters);
    System.out.println("*" + result.getOptionValue("t") + "*");
```

See also the [Usage guide](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html) (although the samples are not consistent, sometimes they use "--test", which does not work for me with version 1.4.)